# Is there a service like skyscanner for trains? One which includes all train companies' timetables.

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there a service like skyscanner for trains?

I mean a comprehensive web service including all train companies' timetables so I'm sure I'm not ignoring any train connection.

Comment: Services that involve train are most likely to be region specific. Which country are you from?

Comment: The issue is that I need to know all trains for an international connection: Amsterdam - Strasbourg

Comment: http://www.raileurope.co.uk/ doesn't help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [Bahn.de (english page)](http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query.exe/e) offers timetables and a trip planner for European train travel.

The rail travel site [Seat61](http://www.seat61.com/) mentions [a couple of quirks and suggestions regarding Bahn.de](http://www.seat61.com/Europe-train-travel.htm#.UW6utKJwrSh) (under "How to check European train times"):

- place names are not always anglicized
- timetables are for major rail operators only
- timetables change in June and December
- it shows timetables only -- not fares (it shows and sells fares for trains operating within Germany)